# Exploit/DoS applications with a 0 width and 0 height image

Tags: vulnerability, denial-of-service, image

I believe I've read multiple times that many applications can't properly handle  0x0 pixel images, but I can't get a hold of such an article right now.

From what I recall, the vulnerability was mainly used to DoS an application, like an online image editor.

Is that actually used or is it just a theoretical attack?

<strike>If so, how does one create a 0x0 pixel graphic?</strike>

Comment: How to create a 0 pixel image is off-topic here (image processing). Before asking if it is a real attack, it would be nice if you could confirm that it is actually a suggested attack ....

Comment: I've updated the question due to the image processing comment. I'll do some further research and update the post again with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These type of bugs cause DOS attacks when the image parser or the renderer fails to parse the image. However, its not that only 0x0 or 1x1 images can invoke such situations. Say, a normal file which targets a certain parameter from the parser can lead to similar attacks. its all how the software is processing the image file.

Check this one out:
[Cool PDF Image Stream - Buffer Overflow (Metasploit)](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/24876/)
The Above vulnerability triggers due to a malformed image file. A good example for your research and yes, these attacks are not theoretical

Answer (score 0):

Smal invisible pixels are mainly used as a tracking method. Every time the containing page is viewed in a viewer which shows images a request is sent to the hosting server. This is also called a Web Bug or Tracking Pixel. But it is also used in HTML E-Mails.

Don't know of any modern software which actually crashes when it sees a 0x0 graphic. Note that the tracking property also (better) works with larger images.

Comment: I'm aware of the tracking use of small images. I'll do some further research and report back with the 0x0 pixel attack.